# How to I stretch my item container and set bottom and top margin?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, grid, material-ui

I'm using `Material-UI` library on `ReactJS`, but I'm having some issues with flexbox.

I want to set my `Item Container` in the center of my `div`, stretching it to take all the height available and set `Bottom and Top margin`.

I'm trying with `alignItems="stretch"` but it doesn't work (Original version code).
I can certainly set the height of the `Grid Item and Paper to 100%`, but I don't see this as an elegant way to make the element fill all the vertical space (Second version code). 
More, if I set Grid Item height and Paper height to 100%, and set top margin and bottom margin to both element, Paper ignores the bottom margin completely. 
More again, the width and height goes over the screen size (see second image belowe), why this happens?

Original version:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    height: "100%"
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
}));

export default function CenteredGrid() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container style={{height: "100%", backgroundColor:"green"}} justify= "center" alignItems="stretch"spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Second version:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    height: "100%"
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    height: "100%",
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
}));

export default function CenteredGrid() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container style={{height: "100%", backgroundColor:"green"}} justify= "center" alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12} style={{backgroundColor: "red", marginTop:10, marginBottom:10}}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my index.css, where I set all the component to height="100%".

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;

  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div#root {
  height: 100%; /* remove this line to see div.app is no more 100% height */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: indigo;
}

div.app {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cornsilk;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
    monospace;
}
```

My expected result is a Grid Item with a Paper element inside it, that is centered inside the Grid container, stretched height to fill all the vertical space but some prefixed bottom and top margin.

My Original Code Result: [image]

My Second version Code Result: [image]

**Plus:**

I've used React Native and I feel like flexbox on mobile phone is more "straightforward". Do you have some resources and tutorial to understand very well how I can handle UI in Reactjs with code examples?

Comment: Can you please create a simple demo on codesandbox or codepen? it will be easy to help you using a demo.

Comment: Hi, 
sorry, you are right. 

Here is the link to sandbox: 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-zgkod

Comment: check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this codesandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-zkv07?fontsize=14) I have fixed the code for you. If you want to remove the `red border` as well, just set `padding:0` for the `item-container`.

Also, another suggestion, don't mix the styles. You are using **inline styling** as well as **creating styles using `makeStyle`**. Use only one, so you have a single source to change whenever you need to make any changes.